# Can't set breakpoint in Chrome with Babel and Webpack

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, webpack, babeljs, source-maps

I have started a new project using the "new" stack: React+Webpack+Babel.

I am trying to explore of this work, and I am facing an issue with debugging in chrome. I can't set breakpoints on some lines in source files when I use Babel and Webpack. (I create sourcemaps).
I would like to be able to debug JSX files.

I have set a little project to reproduce the problem.
https://github.com/pierre-hilt/babel_webpack_sourcemap.git

Here is my configuration:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './build/index',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      }
      ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
}
```

babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

App.jsx (I try to break on line 6 but it is impossible...)

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: props.title,
    };
  }

  changeTitle(newTitle) {
    this.setState({ title: newTitle });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is {this.state.title}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = { title: PropTypes.string };

export default App;
```

I tried different devtool options (cheap, module, ...).
I also tried Babel loader, but is does not work either.

Do you have any idea? Is it a known issue?

Comment: Hmm, seems like a bug with Chrome to me. Have filed an issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606380 In the meantime, would adding a debugger statement work?

Comment: Yes debugger works, but it is not a reasonable solution for long term project :) OK I will have a look thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a workaround that works fine!

babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Babel script

```
"babel": "babel client -d build --source-maps",
```

webpack config

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './build/index',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
   module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      }
      ],
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }
  ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
}
```

I first transpile JSX with babel only, then I transpile ES2015 with babel loader and webpack.

At the end I got source files where I can set break points anywhere!